# Place ID gives "NOT FOUND" error for place details API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have place id's saved in my application which are given by Nearby places API. But if I try to make the place details API call using 
the saved place ID
I get below mentioned error :
`{ "html_attributions" : [], "status" : "NOT_FOUND" }`

Below are the few place id's where I have noticed the same issue:

- ChIJ2fF6zviX9YgRflKEZNrpLrQ
- ChIJ3Xv8KdzrwIcRFe9mz07_mAc
- ChIJA_z3Ds7pwIcR0tmWoD-FxnA
- ChIJb2WasR4P9YgRLEtgoc960w0
- ChIJC-jidC7Mt4kRUaicF-NRL3k
- ChIJezHD6b3H2YgRstKX39Etw84
- ChIJN66KdLO09YgR2mBp6HrMFmY
- ChIJS-L0ef-h9YgRxKmyYOSCJ8s
- ChIJu5l5tzpfwIcRuI97aq-VSYU

Can someone provide me with information why I am not getting the place details with the valid place id(I am assuming that the place id is correct as its returned by Google nearby API).

Comment: How are you retrieving the place details?

Comment: Using API :                     
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=ChIJ2fF6zviX9YgRflKEZNrpLrQ&key=API_KEY

Comment: Where do those place ids come from?  When were they returned?  Did they work at one time?

Comment: The place ID's were returned by Google Nearby places API https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=33.559200000,-84.411600000&key=API_KEY&rankby=distance&pagetoken=              

Below are some of the details there were saved for the place id "ChIJ-0Z7rGz79IgRpJjzfxFr-PA" 
store_id : ee0ce4a8a9ab51b7ef14b0f9da811496b00d0a9f
name  : The Home Depot
vicinity : 680 Lamar Hutcheson Parkway, Riverdale
type  : ["hardware_store", "home_goods_store", "point_of_interest", "store", "establishment"]

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be intended behavior for Google's Places API and place IDs. Google's [documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/places/place-id#save-id) states:

> You may occasionally receive a `NOT_FOUND` status code when you use a
>   saved place ID.
>
> A place ID may become obsolete if a business closes or moves to a new
>   location.
>
> Place IDs may change due to large-scale updates on the Google Maps
>   database. In such cases, a place may receive a new place ID, and the
>   old ID returns a `NOT_FOUND` response.

A solution to this is also provided by Google:

> Best practice is to refresh your stored place IDs
>   periodically. You can refresh Place IDs free of charge, by making a
>   Place Details request, specifying only the ID field in the `fields`
>   parameter. This will trigger the Places Details - ID Refresh SKU.
>
> However, this request might also return `NOT_FOUND` status code. One
>   strategy is to store the original request that returned each place ID.
>   If a place ID becomes invalid, you can re-issue that request to get
>   fresh results. These results may or may not include the original
>   place. The request is chargeable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I re-issue new place ID for a place ID that has been invalid?  Also "One strategy is to store the original request that returned each place ID" - what does this statement means? I do save the original request of nearby place API, but when I get NOT_FOUND status code, the same nearby place API does not return the place.

Comment: Happy to help! :) What this means is that you can store the original Nearby Search request, e.g.: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY so that if you find a place id isn't valid anymore you can make this request again to get the up-to-date results (with valid place ids).

Comment: And this is how you can re-issue a new place id for a place id that is invalid; by making the same nearby search request again that gave you that (now invalid) place id. Note that Google states "These results may or may not include the original place.". Hope this clarifies your doubts!

Comment: The nearby place API does sometimes does not the place and hence the updated place ID. Also, the place ID that is returned first by nearby API, I use it sometime later to get the place details. So if the place ID becomes invalid, there are no place details returned. Also, I tried making the place details API passing the older place ID and the id field in the place details API. But there were no valid place details. Any help or solution that can help me to get the place details if place ID becomes invalid in the above scenario?

Comment: As Google states, "These results may or may not include the original place." and "A place ID may become obsolete if a business closes or moves to a new location.". You need to make the same request again to get the updated place ID, and it's not guaranteed that the place will be returned this time. The one and only solution is to call Nearby Search again, for each place that has an invalid place ID. Let me know if this helps!